# Query timeout in Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle, stored-procedures

I want to see if a prediction made for an ETA of a bus has an actual message. I wrote this query and it times out. Am I doing something wrong? Is there any optimization that helps here?

```
SELECT
P.ROUTE,
P.CODE,
(
    SELECT  COUNT(*)
    FROM    MESSAGE M
    WHERE   M.SENTDATE BETWEEN P.ARRIVAL-(20/60/24) AND P.ARRIVAL+(2/60/24)
    AND TRIM(SUBSTR(M.LOCATIONINFO, 3, 10))  = P.ROUTE
    AND TRIM(SUBSTR(M.LOCATIONINFO, 25, 10)) = P.CODE
)
CNT
FROM
(
    SELECT  *
    FROM    PREDICTION P
    WHERE   P.ARRIVAL BETWEEN TO_DATE('2012/07/04 04:30:00', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS')   
    AND TO_DATE('2012/07/04 04:30:10', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS')
    AND P.ROUTE ='7'
    AND P.CODE  ='2179'
)
P
```

Comment: @notfed Thanks for the edit but the way it was; was formatted by Oracle itself.

Answer (score 1):

To really know what is going on, we would need to see the query plan.  In the meantime, try rewriting your query to have an explicit join:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt
FROM (SELECT  *
      FROM PREDICTION P
      WHERE P.ARRIVAL BETWEEN TO_DATE('2012/07/04 04:30:00', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS') AND TO_DATE('2012/07/04 04:30:10', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS')AND
            P.ROUTE ='7' AND
            P.CODE  ='2179'
     ) P join
     MESSAGE M
     on M.SENTDATE BETWEEN P.ARRIVAL-(20/60/24) AND P.ARRIVAL+(2/60/24) AND
        TRIM(SUBSTR(M.LOCATIONINFO, 3, 10)) = P.ROUTE AND
        TRIM(SUBSTR(M.LOCATIONINFO, 25, 10)) = P.CODE
```

You are doing a rather complicated join.  How large are the two tables?  Do they have any indexes?

I would suggest trying:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt
FROM (SELECT  *
      FROM PREDICTION P
      WHERE P.ARRIVAL BETWEEN TO_DATE('2012/07/04 04:30:00', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS') AND TO_DATE('2012/07/04 04:30:10', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS')AND
            P.ROUTE ='7' AND
            P.CODE  ='2179'
     ) P join
     MESSAGE M
     on M.SENTDATE BETWEEN P.ARRIVAL-(20/60/24) AND P.ARRIVAL+(2/60/24) AND
        TRIM(SUBSTR(M.LOCATIONINFO, 3, 10)) = '7' AND
        TRIM(SUBSTR(M.LOCATIONINFO, 25, 10)) = '2179'
```

These are equivalent.  However, in the original case, Oracle may see a complicated, three-part join and not use the right index.  In the second case, it should use the SENTDATE index, which should speed up the query.

Comment: Message table is very very large but have some indexes (on SENTDATE for example). PREDICTION table is not very large but it has indexes too (on ARRIVAL, CODE, ROUTE and MADEAT).

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if it resolves the issue (and that the results are correct!):

```
SELECT COUNT(M.*) CNT
FROM
    PREDICTION P
INNER JOIN
    MESSAGE M
ON  M.SENTDATE BETWEEN P.ARRIVAL-(20/60/24) AND P.ARRIVAL+(2/60/24)
AND TRIM(SUBSTR(M.LOCATIONINFO, 3, 10))  = P.ROUTE                         
AND TRIM(SUBSTR(M.LOCATIONINFO, 25, 10)) = P.CODE  
WHERE P.ARRIVAL BETWEEN TO_DATE('2012/07/04 04:30:00', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS') AND TO_DATE('2012/07/04 04:30:10', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS')                         
AND P.ROUTE ='7'                         
AND P.CODE  ='2179'
```

Comment: Thanks; But with COUNT(M.*) it does not work and with COUNT(*) it times out.

Comment: Could you try with COUNT(M.CODE) or something like that? I don't know your schema so I don't know if it's feasible for you!

Comment: It did not work too :( and I have edited the query too. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Apart from changing your query to use a join rather than a subquery (as was already suggested), you could also try to

- get rid of the trim(substr(...)) in the comparison for route and code because this will render any indexes on locationinfo useless
- get rid of the quotes around 7 and 2179 (assuming route and code are numeric fields)